# Jetty configuration. ThreadPool

Tags: java, configuration, jetty

I'm trying to choose the best implementation of the threadpool for jetty configuration. But I can't find a way how to compare they. I haven't found any documentation about it. Of course I can see at source code, but on the first look it's hard to define the difference.

May be somebody knows what the difference between org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool, org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.OldQueuedThreadPool and ExecutorThreadPool?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing javadoc:

- ExecutorThreadPool: Jetty ThreadPool using java 5 ThreadPoolExecutor This class wraps a ExecutorService as a ThreadPool and LifeCycle interfaces so that it may be used by the Jetty org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server

The others...

- QueuedThreadPool seems to be implemented before java 5
- OldQueuedThreadPool ... ¿? seems old unremoved code

If you are in doubt... do test with jmeter: http://jmeter.apache.org

Comment: yes, those are threadpools we have grown away from, there used to be a BoundedThreadPool in jetty6 which was replaced by the much better QueuedThreadPool but that was back when we needed to support java 1.4 in the core of jetty, jetty-7 remained largely java 1.4 or 1.5 and then jetty-8 required 1.6 for the servlet-api 3.0 anyway so we were able to update some of those basic classes.  jetty-9 is going to be servlet 3.1 once that is released (likely 9.1 timeframe) but that will require java 1.7 so we just jumped to that version for it.